# What is typescript Number Range

Tags: javascript, typescript

What is range of typescript number types and, after completion into JavaScript, then what is the behaviour?

```
var num  =100000000000
```

Comment: It's all javascript if you want to learn the min/max value you can find them as fields in the `Number` object

Comment: In Javascript max number: 1.7976931348623157e+308 :) In typescript you cannot define range. But you can set predefined values like type t =1|2|3|4 and there is an open suggestion to allow type t= 1..10000 to allow a range. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript just uses JavaScript so whatever numeric value limitations are going to be the same as the JavaScript limitations. Any number you write in that expression will be passed as-is to the JavaScript output.

If you want more information programmatically you can check JavaScript's own `Number.*`.

```
console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE); // 1.7976931348623157e+308
console.log(Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER); // -9007199254740991
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER); // 9007199254740991
```

Do realize however that the `Number` type is a [floating point number](https://modernweb.com/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-floating-points/) so you can't really talk about a "range". It makes more sense talking about the precision.